# Mobiscroll scrolls to bottom of page when clicked

Tags: mobiscroll

Mobiscroll's Date & Time scroller looks very promising.  However, I've noticed that in my webpage and on the Mobiscroll webpage (http://demo.mobiscroll.com/mobile/datetime/date) that:

**when the Mobiscroll Date & Time scroller is activated by clicking inside a properly bound input field, the browser scrolls down to the bottom of the webpage!**

This isn't a very noticeable issue on their demo, since their input field is nearly at the bottom of the webpage (you have to make your browser window very small to notice the unwanted scrolling), but I need the input field to be in the middle of my webpage.  Has anyone implemented the Date & Time selector without the browser window scrolling to the bottom of webpage?  Thanks!

Comment: Here is an issue report on that: https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll/issues/214

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dioslaska!  looks like the fix for issue 214 did fix it on Windows phone, IE 10 on desktop, and Firefox.  Just to make it clear for others out there, as of 3/17/14, the development branch of Mobiscroll on git has the fix for issue 214.

mobiscroll/development git page:
https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll/tree/development

issue 214 details:
https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll/issues/214